# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution. - ionic, capacitor

Tags: android, gradle

Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution
'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip'.
Settings file 'Path:\android\settings.gradle' line: 5
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
Could not read script 'Path:\android\capacitor.settings.gradle' as it does not exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.